# Better way to know if there are any elements left to iterate in for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following for loop:

```
def validate(request, fields=None):
    i = 0
    j = len(fields)
    return_fields = []

    for f in fields:
        i += 1
        if request.data[f] != check_validity(f)
            if i == j:
                return_fields.append(f)
                return return_fields
            else:
                return_fields.append(f)
```

This checks the validity of the fields by some function check_validity(). If it is invalid, it appends it to the return_fields list and at the end, returns it to the main caller. My question is, in my code, I am using two variables i and j to just check if there are any elements left in the list 'fields'. But I am just wondering if there is a better way to do the same operation since I want to return all the invalid fields and not stop when I encounter any 1 of them.

Comment: Why can't you return your `return_fields` after the loop has finished?

Comment: @khelwood: for some reason, I honestly didn't think about that. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another way is to use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):**

```
def validate(request, fields=None):
    return_fields = []

    for i, f in enumerate(fields):
        if request.data[f] != check_validity(f)
            if i+1 == len(fields):
                return_fields.append(f)
                return return_fields
            else:
                return_fields.append(f)
```

**But i don't get it, why you need to know it? Why you can't just:**

```
def validate(request, fields=None):
    for f in fields:
        if request.data[f] != check_validity(f)
            return_fields.append(f)
    return return_fields
```

**Short form:**

```
def validate(request, fields=None):
    return [
        f for f in fields
        if request.data[f] != check_validity(f)
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop automatically finishes when it's iterated all the way through an array, so you can just take the `return` out of the for loop and it'll run once all the elements in fields have been iterated through.

```
def validate(request, fields=None):
    return_fields = []

    for f in fields:
        if request.data[f] != check_validity(f)
            return_fields.append(f)
return return_fields
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def validate(request, fields=None):
    return_fields = []
    buggy = False
    for f in fields:
        if request.data[f] != check_validity(f)
            buggy = True
            return_fields.append(f)
    if buggy: return return_fields
```

BTW in your code, it will return return_fields only when last field is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I guess using yield will be of use for you :) (take a look here [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python) , it is relatively complex, but it is like a return without restarting the function)

```
def validate(request, fields=None):
   for f in fields:
        if request.data[f] != check_validity(f):
            yield (f)
```